# Optimization with joint bounds / symbolic constraint

Tags: scipy, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize, mystic

I am trying to perform least squares optimization on a vector [a1,a2,a3], with the following constraint, where `k` is a constant:

```
-k < a3/a2 < k
```

I will post a simplified version of my code in the hope that this makes it clear enough what I am after.

```py
from scipy import optimize

def loss_function(a_candidate):
    return MyObject(a_candidate).mean_square_error()

def feasibility(a_candidate):
    # Returns a boolean
    k = 1.66711
    a2 = a_candidate[1]
    a3 = a_candidate[2]
    return -k < a3/a2 < k

def feasibility_scipy(a_candidate):
    # As I understand it, for SciPy the constraint has to be a number
    boolean = feasibility(a_candidate)
    if boolean:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

# Equality constraint forcing feasibility_scipy to be 0.
constraint = optimize.NonlinearConstraint(feasibility_scipy, 0, 0)


optimize_results = optimize.minimize(
    loss_function,
    a_init,  # Initial guess
    constraints=constraint)
```

Due to how the initial guess `a_init` is generated, it is in a region where `feasibility` is `False`. (The reason we need to use numerical methods in the first place is that an earlier closed-form method returned an infeasible solution. It is possible to supply a very poor feasible guess like (0,0,0), but this will be much further from the true solution).

Since `constraint`'s gradient is zero almost everywhere, the optimization routine cannot find its way out of this infeasible (inadmissible) region, and it does not terminate successfully. With `SLSQP` it stops after just 1 iteration, with the message `Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem`. With the `trust-constr` solver, it reaches the maximum number of function evaluations, and I believe it has not left the infeasible region because `constr_violation` is `1.0`.

As I understand it, it is not possible in SciPy to provide a 'joint bound' (apologies for invented terminology) on `a2` and `a3`, meaning I am forced to use the `NonlinearConstraint` approach.

What is the proper way to do this? (A few searches have suggested that I may want to try the `mystic` package with a symbolic constraint. But before I invest the time to learn this new package I wanted to see if StackOverflow has a SciPy-based solution. Or if you know how to do this in `mystic` some example code would be very helpful.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I think the solution may be just:

```py
def a_ratio(a_candidate):
    a2 = a_candidate[1]
    a3 = a_candidate[2]
    return a3/a2

feasibility_constraint = optimize.NonlinearConstraint(a_ratio,-k,k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `-k < a3/a2 < k` I would make this two linear constraints:

```
     -k*a2 <= a3
     a3 <= k*a2
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this now

Comment: Is this possible with a [scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint.html)? It looks like the constraint has to be of the form `lb <= A.dot(x) <= ub`.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. E.g. use lb = -999999.

Comment: I mean the dot product part, not the fact that one has to supply ub and lb (and btw you can use `-np.inf` rather than a finite negative value).

Comment: `A` is just a way to specify the coefficients of a bunch of linear constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question has been answered already, but you wanted to know how to approach it in `mystic`.  I'm the `mystic` author.  Something like this:

```
>>> import mystic as my
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> truth = np.array([1,1,1])
>>> 
>>> 
>>> class MyObject(object):
...   def __init__(self, candidate):
...     self.candidate = candidate
...     self.truth = truth
...   def mean_square_error(self):
...     return ((self.truth - self.candidate)**2).sum()
...
>>>
>>> def loss_function(a_candidate):
...    return MyObject(a_candidate).mean_square_error()
...
>>>
```

and then the solution:

```
>>> equations = """
... -k < a3/a2
... a3/a2 < k
... """
>>>
>>> eqn = my.symbolic.simplify(equations, variables=['a1','a2','a3'], locals=dict(k=1.66711), all=False, target='a3')
>>> c = my.symbolic.generate_constraint(my.symbolic.generate_solvers(eqn, variables=['a1','a2','a3']), join=my.constraints.or_)
>>> res = my.solvers.fmin(loss_function, x0=[2,3,4], constraints=c, disp=True, xtol=1e-8)
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 121
         Function evaluations: 229
>>> res
array([1., 1., 1.])
```

What `mystic` does differently is that it builds an "operator" `c` that doesn't allow the optimizer to select infeasible solutions.  Not that it rejects bad solutions with a boolean, but that it transforms "bad" candidates into "good" ones, like this:

```
>>> c([2,10,4])
[2, 10, 4]
>>> c([2,1,4])
[2, 1, 1.6671099999999974]
```